# Can't add more words in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

When I call reality() I want to print Royal Blue but I am getting Royal undefined I am just a beginner in JavaScript Please help me find out what is the problem.

```
var color = "Blue";

function reality() {
  var color = "Royal " + color;
  console.log(color);
}
reality();
```

Comment: Define your variable color inside function reality

Comment: Remove var from color inside function as you already define color as global variable

Comment: Please have a read of the duplicate target. Understanding how variable scope works is crucial when working with JS.

Comment: var color = "Blue";
    
    function reality() {
      color = "Royal " + color;
      console.log(color);
    }
    reality();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please help me find out what is the problem.

In JavaScript, when all the variables declared with `var`, will have the default value of `undefined` unless explicitly something is assigned.

In your case,

```
var color = "Royal " + color;
```

you are using `color` to define the variable `color` itself. So,

```
"Royal " + color
```

will become

```
"Royal " + undefined
```

That is why the result is `Royal undefined.

---

Basically, the variable `color` declared within the `reality` shadows the variable, declared outside the scope of that function. So, you need to choose a different name.

```
var color = "Blue";

function reality() {
  var realityColor = "Royal " + color;
  console.log(realityColor);
}
reality();
```

will print

```
Royal Blue
```

---

**Note:** If you actually meant to modify the `color` variable declared outside, then you should not define a variable called `color` in `reality` and instead, you should access it directly, like this

```
var color = "Blue";

function reality() {
  color = "Royal " + color;
  console.log(color);
}
reality();
```

But, this function doesn't return anything. To make it better, you can return the value and assign it the variable, like this

```
var color = "Blue";

function reality() {
  return "Royal " + color;
}

color = reality();
console.log(color);
```

Comment: Thanks, for this very detailed answer, I am learning about global vs local variable and this is where the question come from.

If I don't write "var" in front color inside the function reality then it will be a global variable, I want the color variable value as "Blue" globally and "Royal Blue" inside the function reality. is it possible?

For example:
console.log(color);
going to print Blue

and

reality()
going to pring Royal Blur

Comment: @imondal007 It will not become a global variable immediately. What happens is, when you try to access a variable, JavaScript will look for its declaration in the current scope, if it is not there, it will go to the scope above, if not there, above that. It goes on, till it reaches the global scope.

Comment: @imondal007 If all you care about is printing, then just do `console.log("Royal " + color)` without any declaration statement

Comment: Printing is not the issue, I really asked this question from learning more about the use of local & global variable. I think I need to know more about JavaScript to understand what you guys are talking about. Thank you again :)

Comment: Now I understand, Local variable gonna ignore the existence of any other variable of same name :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var color = "Blue";
function reality() {
  color = "Royal " + color;
  console.log(color);
}
reality();
```

Color is defined globally, so can be changed inside a function, however if you are defining again it takes null which is undefined.

Comment: It that case, Royal Blue become the value of global variable. I want this only inside reality function not globally

Comment: in that case you define one more local variable called _color and assign the global values, so that blue will be global, and royal blue will be local.